# How to print length of a line in a file (sans newlines)

Tags: python, string, file, strip, string-length

I have an assignment where I need to output the first character of a line plus the length of said line after stripping the newlines from the file.

Here's my code:

```
with open("/usercode/files/books.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line[0] + str(len(line)).strip('\n'))
```

The file reads:

```
Some book
Harry Potter
To Kill a Mockingbird
```

And the output should be:

```
S9
H12
T21
```

But the output I get is:

```
S10
H13
T22
```

Why is the program erroneously printing the length one character too high?

Comment: You're stripping the newline from the wrong string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calling len and then transform the value into a string which you then strip, this is not what you want. Try:

```
with open("/usercode/files/books.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line[0] + str(len(line.strip('\n'))))
```